# How to make copying command from website to terminal secure?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, browser

Today I found intriguing example [website-terminal-copy-paste](http://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste).
For example you may need to clone git repository. In webpage it looks like:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kup/kup.git
```

but when you copy it terminal it becomes:

```
git clone /dev/null; clear; echo -n "Hello ";whoami|tr -d '\n';echo -e '!\nThat was a bad idea. Don'"'"'t copy code from websites you don'"'"'t trust!
Here'"'"'s the first line of your /etc/passwd: ';head -n1 /etc/passwd
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kup/kup.git
```

because the rest is hidden:

```
<p class="codeblock">
      <!-- Oh noes, you found it! -->
      git clone
      <span style="position: absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px">/dev/null; clear; echo -n "Hello ";whoami|tr -d '\n';echo -e '!\nThat was a bad idea. Don'"'"'t copy code from websites you don'"'"'t trust!<br>Here'"'"'s the first line of your /etc/passwd: ';head -n1 /etc/passwd<br>git clone </span>
      git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kup/kup.git
    </p>
```

Of course it can be any command. So my question is how to make sure we don't get malicious code.

Is copying from website, pasting it to text editor(that show non-priniting character), checking the commands and copy-paste to terminal secure way to avoid this kind of attacks?

**EDIT:**

**Probably the best way is never paste anything from website directly to terminal.** Check this case:

```
<h1>Welcome on my tutorial site</h1>

<h3>Below code learn you how to use echo command. Copy both commands and paste it to your terminal</h6>

<hr/>
<p class="codeblock" >
      <!-- Oh noes, you found it! -->
      echo Line1;
      <pre style="position: absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px">echo "Owned";</pre>
      echo Line2;
    </p>
<hr/>
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2x1r18vr/3/)**</kbd>

When you copy and paste it to terminal, command 1 and hidden will be executed immediately. You won't get a chance to check it in terminal.

Comment: I dont know if there is a secure way to do this, however one should always be skeptical of outside sources.

Comment: @Keltari Of course user should be sceptical about outside sources. The point is **`what you see is not what you get`**. You can copy from tutorial `ls -l` and it can be anything. I know that user can retype command or git location

Comment: Well, you can use a clipboard inspector.

Comment: You can copy the command into a basic text editor (best to use one that shows non-printing characters) and then re-copy/paste from there after you see the text.  Of course, that assumes that the text editor you are using has no mechanism for hiding text.

Comment: @MosheKatz This is my last sentence in question.

Comment: @lad2025 You asked whether it's safe, and I said that, barring any issues with your text editor, it is.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid this exploit vector because it's a browser thing and browsers copy text based on the HTML. I suppose it could be possible for browsers to implement some kind of selection tool that works on the visual output to determine what text has been selected. Or disallow selecting text that is being rendered far away from the selection rectangle. But the current selection model doesn't really allow that and it's much harder to create a selection that would work on a rectangle (especially where formatting is concerned). Your editor approach is as good as it gets, I think.

Comment: It can even be more dangerous than I thought. I've attached new demo.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how paranoid you want to be. But to be safe you should first make sure you understand the command and then type it in yourself.

If you don't trust the source do not accept any input from it without sanitizing it.

Comment: It is not about being paranoid or trusting sources. The key point is that I can validate commands on site(understand what it does) but when I copy-paste it it can hide anything for example additional switch to command. It is easy to overlook it. As I've written **`what you see is not what you can get`**

Comment: It is all about (not) trusting a source. The whole reason you want to validate that what you get is actually what you see is evidence that you don't trust the source or the medium. Typing it in yourself is by far the easiest, most universal (because it doesn't rely on the availability of any tool) and fastest (if you can touch type) way to achieve what you asked.